# Accessing the correct requested url in loopback.js

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have the following configuration in my `config.json`

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/eth/v1",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 3001,
  "remoting": {
    "context": false,
    "rest": {
      "handleErrors": false,
      "normalizeHttpPath": false,
      "xml": false
    },
    "json": {
      "strict": false,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "urlencoded": {
      "extended": true,
      "limit": "100kb"
    },
    "cors": false
  }
}
```

And my `server.js` contains the following:

```
'use strict';

var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

app.start = function() {
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');

    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);

    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (require.main === module) app.start();
});
```

The above is pretty standard. MY code is as follows:

```
var server = require('../server');
console.log(server.get('url'));
```

When I do `curl localhost:3001`, it prints out `http://localhost:3001` which is as expected.

However, if I add the following in my `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost locahost-testnet
```

and try to access like this `curl localhost-testnet:3001`, it still prints 
`http://localhost:3001` which is not what I expect.

What should I do to get the accessed url? (`http://localhost-testnet:3001`)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by defining remoteHook for your model something like below:

```
yourModel.beforeRemote('**', function(ctx, user, next) {
    console.log(ctx.req.headers.host); 
    // this will print "localhost-testnet:3001" in your case
    next();
});
```

Remote hooks with wildcards runs before any remote method is called. [Doc](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html)